# Possible reason for TCP response not getting sent?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, twisted

Any reason as to why the TCP responses would not be sent even though the connection is active. (i.e we are able to receive the TCP stream the same time over same connection)

The TCP connection is setup using Twisted(Python)

To summarise your system.

- Our application (let say B) is connected to a application A over TCP.
- B is also connected to C (a separate service)  over 0MQ via IPC (I
  believe it's a Unix socket)
- C connected to PostgresSQL over TCP (over SSL)

Normal message flows look like this

```
A --TCP--> B -- IPC(0MQ) --> C (C query DML over TCP to Postgres)
                               |
                               |
A <--TCP-- B <-- IPC(0MQ) <-- C (DML Result)
```

Now, some time(happens randomly) responses to TCP server(i.e from B to A) are not being sent.

We have confirm the above using the following `ngrep` (where x.x.x.x is the IP or the TCP server)

```
ngrep -d eno1 -pqtW byline net x.x.x.x
```

But our logs has entry says that responses(from B) that are sent(which is written after we **write the response over TCP**) to A.

```
def send_tcp_response_to_sms800(self,response):
    self.log.info("Sending TCP response for message id {message_id}",message_id=response[0])
    message = self.create_message(response)
    ber_enc_message = ber_encoder.encode(message)
    self.transport.write(b'\x7e\x7e\x7e\x7e')
    self.transport.write(struct.pack('>I', len(ber_enc_message)))
    self.transport.write(ber_enc_message)  ## <-- response written to TCP
    self.log.info("response sent to sms800 from {qs}",qs=self.queue_server_name)
    timestamp = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
    self.log_message_id_in_response(response[0],timestamp) ## <-- ## log file where message id from the response is logged
```

Just to be safe this not related to memory

```
ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30933
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I have ran out of idea as to what could be possible reason for this.

Note: **We have check thoroughly, communication between B to C is not a problem over here. We have cross check the logs of both B and C applications and found a matching pair of request/response between B and C.**

Comment: Sorry if this sounds offensive, but have you tried using ``tcpdump`` or wireshark to sniff the traffic?  You seem to be following some sort of protocol (I assume), are you following that correctly?  In other words, if ``b'\x7e\x7e\x7e\x7e'`` and ``struct.pack('>I', len(ber_enc_message))`` were invalid, would that cause node ``A`` to disregard ``ber_enc_message``?  Or it could be a timing issue, ie. one of the messages is sent before or after another.  The code you've provided looks good to me otherwise.

Comment: @notorious Yes I have being sniffing the packet using ngrep can't find any reason as to why sending packet stop all of a sudden. Even if `node A disregard the message` we would still be able to sniff it.